# PHPDoc dynamic namespace with inheritance

Tags: php, phpdoc

I have some pseudocode

```
<?php
namespace Parent {

    class Helper{
        public $a;
    }

    class Test{
        /**
        * @var Helper
        */
        public $helper;

        public function __construct() {
            $reflection = new \ReflectionClass($this);
            $name = $reflection->getNamespaceName() . "\Helper";
            $this->helper = new $name;
        }
    }

}

namespace Child {

    class Helper{
        public $b;
    }

    class Test extends \Parent\Test {}
}
```

In this PHPDoc property \Child\Test->helper have link to \Parent\Helper.

For PHPStorm and phpDocumentor `@var Helper` equal to `@var \Parent\Helper`. And when in try get autocomplete for `$this->helper` inside `\Child\Test` i get method only from `\Parent\Helper`

How should i rewrite my phpdoc block?

Answer (score 0):

Override the property in the subclass to put the fully qualified namespace there:

```
class Test extends \Parent\Test
{
    /**
     * @var \Child\Helper
     */
    protected $helper;
```

Note that the property needs to be protected (or public) in the parent.

Yet another alternative would be to use an interface for the Helper and then change the DocBlock on the property to denote the interface, e.g.

```
@var HelperInterface
```

This is assuming your Helpers share the same API though.

Also see the [docs for PHPDocumentor explaning how to annotate types.](http://phpdoc.org/docs/latest/guides/types.html)

Comment: For PHPStorm and phpDocumentor `@var Helper` equal to `@var \Parent\Helper`. And when in try get autocomplete for `$this->helper` inside `\Child\Test` i get method only from `\Parent\Helper`

Comment: @Hello then override the property in the subclass